# Cart shows as empty after change of page

Tags: virtocommerce

I'm encountering a weird issue, on the frontend, whenever I add a product to the cart it will be added there and the icon gets updated to show the 1 to indicate there's an item.

[image: Step 1]

Whenever I change the page, the cart gets shown as being empty.

[image: Step 2]

In this step I'll add a product again, now it will show the updated cart (the old content will be present too).

[image: Step 3]

I'd expect the content of the cart to always be shown on the frontend. I suspect the issue lies with the theme or caching, but I'm not entirely sure. I hope someone can help me out here with debugging or resolving the issue.

I'm using the [vc-theme-material theme](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-theme-material).

Using version `2.13.28`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the request to update the cart on initial load was missing. I've submitted a PR you can see here: https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-theme-material/pull/15.

If you want to fix it yourself, edit `assets/rt.global.js` to inlcude the following function:

```
function updateCart() {
    Shopify.getCart(function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery("body").removeClass("is_loading"),
            roar.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                roar.closeThemeCtl2()
            }, 5e3)
        }, 500), Shopify.updateCartInfo(e, ".cart-info")
    })
}
```

And execute it on init load:

```
var GLOBAL = {
    common: {
        init: function () {
            updateCart()
            // other code
        }
    }
},
```

Example of the full snippet after edits can be found here: https://github.com/S3B4S/vc-theme-material/commit/44785616bf614f727b094c308957ae0bf8da173a

Answer (score 0):

This theme is outdated and will not be supported. Try using https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-theme-default as the base theme for the project.